# how do i erase all info on macbook air while still keeping microsoft word

Tags: macbook-pro

I received a  macbook with unwanted materials on it and i would like to start anew, but i need Microsoft Word for college. I am to afraid to try anything in fear of erasing the program. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for a clean slate would be to wipe the drive and reinstall OS X. However, if you really need to keep Microsoft Word you might want to try other options.

For data that the old owner did not delete, you can create yourself an account on the machine (Administrator) and delete their account.

[image: Add admin account]

Then, using Disk Utility, you can "erase free space" to actually delete the data.

[image: Disk Utility]

As for the rest of the stuff on the drive, such as installed applications that you don't want, you will need to manually remove these from `/Applications`. I suggest that you don't simply delete the `.app` files from that directory, but run them through a 3rd party uninstaller such as [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

This is a lot less "clean" than reinstalling OS X, but it does what you want.

Comment: I'd just add that you can delete any old accounts as well which will free up space - as long as you have created a new admin account you're fine deleting any other user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a little flash drive with an amazing amount of GB - and there's your answer.

Comment: Please can you expand this answer to explain how the flash drive could be used in this situation. This would help the questioner better understand any risks involved with this approach.

Comment: Sorry, OP, I meant that you can copy, temporarily or permanently, anything you fear you might lose onto a properly formatted Flash drive (use Disk Utility.) Limited only by the size of your files or even entire user account, and the size of the drive.